# How to configure to configure the default transient instance injection

Tags: c#, .net-core

Sometimes we miss adding a type of implementation to our service, this is unnoticed until we run or debug the service, and we get the following error message

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IMyType' while attempting to activate 'MyType'.

Here is the code example we configured:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
         
                services.AddTransient<SqlHelper, SqlHelper>();
                services.AddTransient<Helper, Helper>();
                services.AddTransient<CacheHandler, CacheHandler>();
            });
}
```

Is there any way to configure any missing implementation type to Transient by default?

Comment: Please do not add unrelated or misleading tags to your question. I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this question is not about using the Visual Studio application, and I've removed the `[.net]` tag because this question is not about .NET Framework (it's about .NET Core instead).

Comment: You could use reflection to go over all classes that have a concrete implementation and an interface as add it to the service collection. This makes the assumption you always have 1 interface to 1 implementing class.

Comment: Wow, why not .net itself gives an option to configure the default implementation type for any missing entry?  why they want us to type a lot :)

Comment: @ImranRizvi Because most people wouldn't use it, and it would be a dangerous assumption to make. It's better to get an error telling you you've forgotten to configure a service than it would be for the framework to magically pick the wrong service implementation and potentially corrupt your data.

Comment: @Imran I can think of a good reason not to. Imagine this scenario: you have a service that has to be registered as Scoped for your application to function correctly. You forget to register this service, but it automatically gets registered as Transient. Your service now has a subtle bug that's difficult to pin down. In reality, we can also ask "why did it take so long for C# to get negative pattern matching?" (`if (a is not b)` rather than `if (!(a is b))`), and it's simply that such a feature wasn't thought of or deemed necessary by developers at the time.

Comment: Why would I forget, when I will configure it to have transient by default. If I have a mixed scope, I will keep the large ones as default and prefer to put fewer ones manually. Anyways is there any way to put the default settings?

Comment: Why would you forget? Uh, because unless I'm wrong about the state of AI, you're human.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with the default injection dependency provider, but you can use [a other provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement).

Dryloc (a alternative provider) has mechanisms that allow us to intervene when a service could not be retreived. In the next example, when a service isn't retreived then a new instance is injected :

**Program.cs** :

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(
            new DryIocServiceProviderFactory(
                new Container(rules => 
                    rules.WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations((type, key) =>
                    {
                        // Use the condition delegate to log unregistered service
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Unregistered service : {type}");
                        return true;
                    })
                )
            )
        )
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

`UseServiceProviderFactory` configure the host to use a other service provider.

[WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RulesAndDefaultConventions.md#withconcretetypedynamicregistrations) add the rule to return a new instance if the service asked is a concrete type (struct or class not abstract).